Implementing generics on Laravel's LengthAwarePaginator
I want to improve the typing around our use of Laravel's pagination feature. To do that I'm trying to use generics via PHPDoc. I've made our own paginator class that extends Laravel's, with docblocks for the types:
/**
 * @template T
 */
class MyPaginator extends LengthAwarePaginator
{
    /**
     * @return array<T>
     */
    public function items(): array
    {
        return parent::items();
    }
}

and I'm returning it from a method like this:
/**
 * @return MyPaginator<CampaignTemplateListDto>
 */
public function list(): MyPaginator
{
    // ... code omitted for brevity

    // $paginator is Laravel's LengthAwarePaginator
    $paginator = $query->paginate();
    
    return new MyPaginator($paginator->items(), $paginator->total(), $paginator->perPage(), $paginator->currentPage());
}

but my IDE (PhpStorm) isn't recognizing that the type coming out of items() is an array of CampaignTemplateListDto, it thinks it's mixed:

In fact, I don't know where it's getting mixed from at all, because both MyPaginator::items() and LengthAwarePaginator::items() are both typed to return just an array.
How can I make my IDE understand that MyPaginator::items() is returning an array of CampaignTemplateListDto objects?

The class-level generic annotation should be set up to indicate that MyPaginator works with the type T (in your case CampaignTemplateListDto). You should add the @extends LengthAwarePaginator<T> annotation in the MyPaginator like this:
/**
 * @template T
 * @extends LengthAwarePaginator<T>
 */
class MyPaginator extends LengthAwarePaginator
{
    /**
     * @return array<T>
     */
    public function items(): array
    {
        return parent::items();
    }
}


Unfortunately that's not working, at least in PhpStorm. When iterating over $myPaginator->items() in a foreach loop I'm not getting autocompletion for the properties of CampaignTemplateListDto.
